# Web based database administration and browsing for PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

Do you know any free or affodrable web based database administration and browsing tool for PostgreSQL? Something like phpMyAdmin for MySQL and better than phpPgAdmin.
For MySQL I found Chive that looks promissing. I'm looking for something similiar for PostgreSQL.

Comment: It may be useful if you could list specific features / functionality that you want. What does phpPgAdmin not do that you want to be able to do?

Comment: Well. I need something more user-friendly than phpPgAdmin. It could be Java based but it's not a requirement. I'm creating a developement environment and gathering tools.

Comment: @PiotrGwiazda I checked `Team Postgresql` but right it has a lof of bugs (maybe cuz it is not updated anymore). Did you found or did you use other web admin tools for PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Team Postgresql](http://www.teampostgresql.com/) - Not free but reasonably priced.

Comment: Well I checked this product. The good news is that right now it is free. Bad news - it has a lot of bugs, probably because it is not updated anymore.

Answer (score 2):

Have you checked the [list of PostgreSQL GUI tools](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Community_Guide_to_PostgreSQL_GUI_Tools)?

Comment: Yes. But there are not much web based tools.

Answer (score -1):

phpPGadmin, its on sourceforge

Answer (score -3):

phpPGAdmin

http://phppgadmin.sourceforge.net/